# Parse String into Characters

Tags: c

I want some ideas on parsing a string into character so that I can do manipulation as needed on the characters of the string.I want ideas,pseudocodes are appreciated.Please dont post any code here.

Comment: A string _is_ an array of characters. To manipulate the characters, just go through the array. I don't know what you could be having trouble with, and I don't know what we could possibly help you with.

Comment: String is an array of chars and can be manipulated using pointer. What do you need?

Comment: A string is just a (null terminated) array of characters in C. You don't need to "parse" it into one. Unless you reword your question more specifically, I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over all chars in your string, and check for some characters you need to manipulate. A simple draft could look like:

```
char *str = "some-text";
char *p = str;

while ( *p ) {
 char ch = *p++;
 switch( ch ) {
   case '-': manip1(ch);
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to (probably) `break;` at the end of your `case` labels. Also `while(*p) { switch(*p) { case '-': *p = manip1(*p); break; ... } }` is probably more what OP is looking for (maybe?)

Comment: I think he means changing the contents of `str` so maybe `str[]` could fit better.